# 構造体の変数をコピーする危険性について詳しく教えて下さい。

Tags: go

[こちら](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#copying)にbytes.Buffer型をコピーするときは注意したほうがいいと書いてありますが、副作用に関する記述がよくわかりませんでした。

> the slice in the copy may alias the array in the original, causing subsequent method calls to have surprising effects.

bytes.Bufferの中身は確認してbufというスライスがあるのは確認できました。

```golang
// A Buffer is a variable-sized buffer of bytes with Read and Write methods.
// The zero value for Buffer is an empty buffer ready to use.
type Buffer struct {
    buf      []byte // contents are the bytes buf[off : len(buf)]
    off      int    // read at &buf[off], write at &buf[len(buf)]
    lastRead readOp // last read operation, so that Unread* can work correctly.
}
```

bytes.Buffer型をコピーする際は結局どうすればよろしいでしょうか。
そもそもコピーしてはいけないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- sliceをコピーするというのは、実際にはポインタをコピーしていて、実際の値が格納されているメモリはコピー元とコピー先で同一のものを参照する

  - 参考: [Golang における配列とスライスのコピー時の違い - Qiita](https://qiita.com/k_yuda/items/11fac8895511ed46ce66)の図がわかりやすいかと。
- つまりsliceを持っているような構造体を不用意にコピーしてしまうと、コピー先だけ変更したつもりが、コピー元も同時に変更してしまう、というようなことが起こりうる

  - これはSliceに限らず、構造体のメンバがポインタ型の場合には起こりうる
- このため、提示されたリンク先では、よく知らない別パッケージの構造体の不用意なコピーはするんじゃないぞ、と言っているのだと思います。

バッファをコピーする意図がよくわかりませんが、`byte.Buffer`でバッファリングしてるデータを別のBufferでも持ちたいということであれば、[go - Write (or copy) the contents of one bytes.Buffer to another - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69758147/write-or-copy-the-contents-of-one-bytes-buffer-to-another)に記載されているように、コピー元のバッファを一度書き出して、それをコピー先のバッファで`byte.Buffer.Write`するのが一案かもしれません

※なお、単純にsliceをcopyするようなケースでは、ビルトインのcopy関数を使うと想定したように値まで含めてコピーしてくれます

Comment: わかりやすい回答ありがとうございます。
スライスの理解が足りないことに気づけて良かったです。

Comment: お役に立てたなら何よりです　お手数でなければ回答を承認してもらえれば嬉しいです

Comment: 承認できました！